# "Скидки до 50 процентов!" - это двусоставное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Скидки до 50%!

Это двусоставное предложение? Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 2):

**Скидки до 50%!**

1) **Вы это пишете в рекламе,** это предлагает ваша фирма?

Тогда это **двусоставное** предложение, именная часть сказуемого выражена падежной формой (скидки какие?).

2) **Вы это увидели в рекламе?** Скидки до 50%! Хорошие скидки!

Тогда для вас это **номинативное** предложение, падежная форма является определением к слову *скидки*.